# Django LDAP: How to map extra fields in Active Directory to Django User Database

Tags: django, ldap, ldap-query

I would like to map some of the field available in my companies Active Directory to my Django Application like department, Job Title so on. I am using the Django_auth_ldap for backend authentication and it copies the data and updates the record in the Django application Database. Since, Django Auth User table does not support these attributes what will be your suggestions of doing it? Please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read here,  map AD profile attributes to the django profile.
[http://packages.python.org/django-auth-ldap/#user-objects](https://web.archive.org/web/20120724025709/http://packages.python.org/django-auth-ldap/#user-objects)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looking for exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is documentation from django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/. Have you tried googling? There is already lot of info available for this.